# gnome-keyring asks for "unnamed" key instead of real name

Tags: ssh, password, gnome-keyring

Whenever I try to ssh into a server for the first time, a GUI popup asks for the key password:

`An application wants access to the private key "Unnamed", but it is locked:`

When we look at the processes, we see that it knows very well for which key it asks that (the sysadmin key):

```
 2340 ?        SLl    0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
 6660 ?        S      0:00  \_ /usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/keyring/.ssh
23894 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ /usr/bin/ssh-add /home/philippe/.ssh/sysadmin
23895 ?        SL     0:00      \_ /usr/lib/gcr/gcr-ssh-askpass Enter passphrase for /home/philippe/.ssh/sysadmin:
```

Of course I can enter my password, but without looking at the processes I have to guess which key it is:

```
-rw------- 1 philippe philippe 1.7K Jan 27 2015 id_rsa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 philippe philippe 10 Jan 27 2015 id_rsa.keystore
-rw-r--r-- 1 philippe philippe 407 Jan 27 2015 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 philippe philippe 228K Nov 14 14:01 known_hosts
-rw------- 1 philippe philippe 228K Nov 9 16:46 known_hosts.old
-rw------- 1 philippe philippe 1.8K Jan 27 2015 support
-rw------- 1 philippe philippe 381 Jan 27 2015 support.pub
-rw------- 1 philippe philippe 1.8K Jan 27 2015 sysadmin
-rw------- 1 philippe philippe 381 Jan 27 2015 sysadmin.pub
```

I could be the "support" or the "sysadmin" key, but because the dialog only diplay "Unnamed" I have to remember which server uses which. I think it should display "sysadmin" or "support" instead of "Unnamed".

Here are some additional informations:

```
philippe@pv-desktop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

philippe@pv-desktop:~$ uname -a
Linux pv-desktop 4.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 23 15:48:01 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

philippe@pv-desktop:~$ gnome-keyring version
gnome-keyring: 3.28.0.2
```

I tried using `seahorse` to see if there was a way to edit this "Unnamed" information, but there is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with `seahorse` you can actually rename the key, but it's original name is not "Unnamed" it is "Secure Shell Key".